# extracting links from canvas object

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
history = "https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/2381/F-54T5841G.html"
url="https://web.archive.org/web/*/"+history
driver.get(url)
re.findall('/web/\d+/.*?\.html',driver.page_source)
```

in this case there would be 10 saved response, I would like to get all 10 links for the saved HTMLs 
I tried `re.findall('/web/\d+/.*?\.html',driver.page_source)`  only got two valid links,
in the html it doesn't show which of html `canvas` will contain a link so I can click on them.

Edit 1: Ideally I want a list containing the 10 links

any help is appreciated